# Convert nested array to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to use `reduce` to convert a nested array to an object.

I want to convert `var bookprice = [["book1", "$5"], ["book2", "$2"], ["book3", "$7"]];`

to

```
var bookpriceObj = {
    "book1": "$5", 
    "book2": "$2",
    "book3": "$7"
};
```

here is what I tried

```
var bookprice = [["book1", "$5"], ["book2", "$2"], ["book3", "$7"]];
bookpriceObj = {};
bookprice.reduce(function(a, cv, ci, arr){
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        bookpriceObj [i] = arr[i];

    return bookpriceObj ;
})
```

but the below result is not the desired result

```
{
    ["book1", "$5"]
    ["book2", "$2"]
    ["book3", "$7"]
}
```

Comment: Seems to me like you're trying to use a reducer like it's a for loop, but it's a different concept. Do not reference variables that are outside it, all the things are already in the arguments of the reducer. The same accumulator is passed through the whole thing element by element, and you "collect" things to it (or sum or what have you). But in this case a simple for loop would probably be way faster.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using forEach is shorter

```js
var bookprice = [["book1", "$5"], ["book2", "$2"], ["book3", "$7"]];

var bookpriceObj = {};


bookprice.forEach(e=>bookpriceObj[e[0]] = e[1]);

console.log(bookpriceObj)
```

Comment: You have an entry value, a loop over an array and an end value, it's definitely a fit for `Array.reduce`

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I know, but I'm not a big fan of reduce for this situations, the end value is an object, not a single value (which is the purpose). I think is more clear using loops. In my opinion, reduce() is better to reduce, to find one single value as end value.

Answer (score 4):

You need to return an object from the "reducer" AKA the first argument of reduce, and use an empty object as second argument.

```js
var bookprice = [
  ["book1", "$5"],
  ["book2", "$2"],
  ["book3", "$7"]
];

var result = bookprice.reduce(function(object, el) {
  object[el[0]] = el[1]
  return object;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

You don't need a for loop since reduce already iterates over the array.

Answer (score 4):

You can use reduce with Array Destructoring.

```
    bookpriceObj = bookprice.reduce((a, [b, c]) => (a[b] = c, a), {});
```

**Here's what's happening:**

- `a` is the accumulator which has an initial value of the final parameter passed to `reduce`. The last value we pass is `{}` so it's an object
- Array Destructoring can immediately assign values in an array to variables. a.e. `[a, b] = ["one", "two"]` assigns `a` with a value of `"one"` and `b` with a value of `"two"`
- with each iteration over each item we assign the value of `b`(a.e. "book1") as a property on the object(`a`) and give it a value equal to `c`(a.e. "$2")
- Each iteration of `reduce` you must return the accumulator(`a`)
- When the whole thing is finally done, it'll store in `bookpriceObj` the result!

```js
var bookprice = [ ["book1", "$5"], ["book2", "$2"], ["book3", "$7"]],
bookpriceObj = bookprice.reduce((a, [b, c]) => (a[b] = c, a), {});

console.log(bookpriceObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bookprice.reduce((acc, price) => {
  let tmp = {}
  tmp[price[0]] = price[1]
  return Object.assign(acc, tmp)
}, {})
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.reduce()`, `Array destructuration`, `Dynamical keys` and `Spread operator`.

```js
const bookprice = [
  ['book1', '$5'],
  ['book2', '$2'],
  ['book3', '$7'],
];

const ret = bookprice.reduce((tmp, [
  name,
  price,
]) => ({
  ...tmp,

  [name]: price,
}), {});

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the accumulated object in your reduce function and the for loop is not necessary.

Try:

```
const bookprice = [["book1", "$5"], ["book2", "$2"], ["book3", "$7"]];
const nameIndex = 0;
const priceIndex = 1;

const bookPricesObj = bookprice.reduce((prices, bookInfo) => {
    const name = bookInfo[nameIndex];
    const price = bookInfo[priceIndex];

    prices[name] = price;
    return prices;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert a nested array to an object

```js
var bookprice = [
  ["book1", "$5"],
  ["book2", "$2"],
  ["book3", "$7"]
];
bookpriceObj = bookprice.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[cur[0]] = cur[1];
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(bookpriceObj);
```